# How to do views random sort for all the items in a pager?

Tags: 8, views

I created five nodes:

- Apple
- Pear
- Kiwi
- Orange
- Cheese

Then I created a view with the following settings:

- Show content of type **Fruit**
- Display 1 item per page, use mini pager
- Sort: **Global: Random**

Now I flip through the nodes one at a time as an authenticated user.

There should be five nodes, but I don't see all 5 nodes in a random order; instead, I see some nodes twice, and other nodes not at all.

**Things I tried**

- In the query settings for the view, I have tried toggling DISTINCT on/off and rebuilding the cache; it appears to have no effect.
- I tried setting the views caching to time-based (1 hour), thinking that this would give me all the nodes arranged in a random order that changes each hour, but I still get some nodes twice and others not at all

Is there a way to sort the nodes in a random order and yet still go through the entire set?

**Potential problems with random sorting that don't affect this use case**

- I am only doing this as an authenticated user; [core bug affecting caching that breaks random views for anonymous users](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2352009)
- I have caching turned off in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this, it seems that **when you use a pager, random sort can return the same item on multiple pages**.  In other words, Views random sort will randomly generate a list of results on each page, and you can get repeat results among different pages.

So what do you do if you want a random sort of all view results (on all pages of the pager) with no repeats?

You have to do it yourself.

Here's what I did.

First, add an integer field, **Random Int**.

Then, in `hook_node_presave()`, set the field to a random value.

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave(NodeInterface $node) {
  // Randomize the order in which missed cards appear.
  $node->set('field_int_random', MYMODULE_randomize_repeat_sort());
}

/**
 * Returns a number between 1 and 1000 for randomizing sort.
 *
 * @return int
 *   A random number from 1 to 1000.
 */
function MYMODULE_randomize_repeat_sort() {
  return mt_rand(1, 1000);
}
```

Finally, in your view, sort by the **Random Int** field instead of Views random sort.

Of course, the method here only randomizes the nodes on node save.  For my use case, that is sufficient, but if you want a random sort per user, etc., you will need to do it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

In your view under filter criteria, use Aggregation settings -> group results together.

This should remove your duplicate results

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that didn't work for me.  I tried turning on aggregation for the view (it wasn't on before) and then making sure **Published** and **Content type** both had aggregation set to *Group results together*, but I still get duplicates when I click through the links.